# Simple ForeignKey in ClassBasedView in django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a model with a foreignkey to another model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Organisation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

I want to use a CreateView to be able to create a new Organisation, but be able to enter a new contact person details on the same page (i.e. when a new organisation is created, a new contact person must also be created).

What is the nicest (DRY) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the CreateView use the model that has the ForeignKey and since it inherits the FormMixin's form_class use the modelform_factory for that model with extra fields the fields of ForeignKey's model. Finally, overload either the validation or save methods with a get_or_create with the ForeignKey's model fields, passing the result to the ModelForm.

An alternative approach would be to chain two CreateViews. First with the Organization as the model, using the Contact's CreateView URL as its success_url. You can even use js to replace the first submit with the html of the second view.

Or you can try some hacks floating around utilizing formsets, though I prefer the first two methods in your case. The formset hacks are better suited for many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Do I use the modelform_factory for the Person or Organisation (which has the ForeignKey)? How do I add the extra fields into the form?

Comment: >> Do I use the modelform_factory for the Person or Organisation (which has the ForeignKey)? Organization

>> How do I add the extra fields into the form? By using the formfield_callback parameter on your ForeignKey (contact) to return the name and email fields.